# Reorder the array after removing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my application I'm having a list of items which will be pushed into an array when checking that and will be removed from the array when unchecked.
Here is the code

```
          if (data.selectedInsertion === true) {
                order.push(data);
            }
            else if (data.selectedInsertion === false) {
                angular.forEach(order, function (value,key) {
                    if (value == data) {
                        delete order[key];
                    }
                })
            }
```

The problem is when the 5th element in the array is deleted, the array will be missing that key forever and so when I display it in the template using `angularjs` it will show a blank row in the place or the missing 5th element.How can I re arrange the array after removing the element.

Comment: You have to slice it. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: you might be confusing objects and arrays here.

Comment: If you still _need_ the keys to be present - then don’t _remove_ the elements, but set a value like false or null instead to represent “removed” items.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.selectedInsertion === true) {
    order.push(data);
}
else if (data.selectedInsertion === false) {
    order.splice(order.index(data),1);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: should be order.indexOf(data)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the values in your array are unique, you can do it like this:

```
if(data.selectedInsertion) {
  order.push(data);
} else {
  order.splice(order.indexOf(data),1)
}
```

Array.splice removes elements from an array.
Check this link for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

If `data` is not unique, only the first occurence in the array is removed.

Also, you can leave out the explicit checks for `true` and `false`, especially since it seems to be a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Remember one never use delete to remove elements from an array. As it will remove the element leaving undefined under it's key. Thus, you can splice it or filter it out.

**Filter it out:**

```
if (data.selectedInsertion === true) {
    order.push(data);
}
else if (data.selectedInsertion === false) {
    order = order.filter(function(v){
    return v !== data;
    });
}
```

**Splice it**

```
if (data.selectedInsertion === true) {
    order.push(data);
}
else if (data.selectedInsertion === false) {
    order.splice(order.indexOf(data),1);
}
```

> delete is used to remove a property from an object.